# threading.Condition.wait(timeout) ignores threading.Condition.notify()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, condition-variable

I have an application that uses 2 threads. I want to be able to shut down both threads by waiting for a condition variable `exitCondition`. I am using python 3.3 which unlike python 2.7 makes `threading.Condition.wait()` return `True` when the condition was notified and `False` for when a timeout occured.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
from time import sleep

exitCondition = threading.Condition()

def inputActivity():
    while True:
        exitCondition.acquire()
        exitConditionReached = exitCondition.wait(.1) #<-critical
        print(exitConditionReached)
        exitCondition.release()
        if exitConditionReached: #exitCondition reached -> shutdown
            return
        else: #exitCondition not reached -> do work
            sleep(.1)

inThread = threading.Thread(target = inputActivity)
inThread.start()

sleep(.2) #<-critical

exitCondition.acquire()
exitCondition.notify()
print("exitCondition notified")
exitCondition.release()

inThread.join()
```

There are 2 lines with a `#<-critical` comment in line 10 and 21. If the `sleep`s are "misaligned" (for example .25 and .1) the program will terminate. If the `sleep`s are "aligned" (for example .2 and .1) the `inThread` will run indefinitely printing `false` forever. It looks like a race condition to me, apparently if `notify` is called at the same time as `wait` the notification is not recognized. I was under the impression that the `exitCondition.acquire()` and `exitCondition.release()` were supposed to prevent that. The question is why the condition variable is not thread safe and what I can do about it. Ideally I want to write `wait(0)` with the guarantee that no notification will be swallowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the call to `exitCondition.notify` occurs when the worker thread is doing work (i.e., is in the `sleep(.1)` call (or anywhere else other than the `.wait` call), then the behaviour you describe sounds like exactly what I'd expect.  The `wait` call returns `True` only if the notification happened *during* the `wait`.

It sounds to me as though this is a use-case for a `threading.Event` instead of a `threading.Condition`: replace `threading.Condition` with `threading.Event`, replace the `notify` call with a `set` call, and remove the `acquire` and `release` calls altogether (in both threads).

That is, the code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
from time import sleep

exitCondition = threading.Event()

def inputActivity():
    while True:
        exitConditionReached = exitCondition.wait(.1) #<-critical
        print(exitConditionReached)
        if exitConditionReached: #exitCondition reached -> shutdown
            return
        else: #exitCondition not reached -> do work
            sleep(.1)

inThread = threading.Thread(target = inputActivity)
inThread.start()

sleep(.2) #<-critical

exitCondition.set()
print("exitCondition set")

inThread.join()
```

Once you've got that far, you don't need the first `.wait`: you can replace that with a direct `is_set` call to see if the exit condition has been set yet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
from time import sleep

exitCondition = threading.Event()

def inputActivity():
    while True:
        if exitCondition.is_set(): #exitCondition reached -> shutdown
            return
        else: #exitCondition not reached -> do work
            sleep(.1)

inThread = threading.Thread(target = inputActivity)
inThread.start()

sleep(.2) #<-critical

exitCondition.set()
print("exitCondition set")

inThread.join()
```